# How to add a widget as an icon when install android app

Tags: android, plugins, android-widget, presentation

I see some app on Play Store, when install these apps auto add an icon (to present their new apps if we touched on or any another reason). How to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add this to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

and use this code :

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(getPackageName(), getPackageName());
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, i);
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getPackageName());
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.icon));
shortcutIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        this.sendBroadcast(shortcutIntent);
```

You can change the icon to your application icon and change name of your application

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try to use this code to my app but it not work. I added on onCreate().

Comment: i think you don't add this permission to your manifest, i am checking my code and then send it here, add this to manifest: <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>

Comment: I added it . Can you send me sample project? Thanks

Comment: thanks.. i want to open application on click of shortcut, thanks in advance

Comment: and also when i clicked on icon (short cut) then i can see toast meassage that display that your application is not installed on phone.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub tnx, i remove it.